# Checking jQuery UI Calls

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on an old project from an ex-colleague. In this project the entire jQuery UI 1.8.18 is loaded.

Is there an easy way to check what jQuery UI calls are made so I can remove the unused parts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's `.data("events")`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).  If you know the selector's class or id, then use:

```
$(selector).data("events");
```

If you want to search the entire document, then do the following:

```
$("*").each(function(index, el){
    if($(el).data("events") != undefined){
        //do something
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/SLGdE/3/

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!